# Interactive carousel with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to create a component similar to instagram stories for a few hours. That is nothing more than an interactive carousel, where you can move forward and backward. The thing is, my strategy with setTimeOut fires every time I interact and does not cancel the state, so if the user is in the first photo and clicks 5x in a row to go to the sixth photo, in a few seconds the settimeout will be like a tsunami and the component advances 5x stories in a row starting from 6. I wanted somehow to reset my timer every time the user clicks on a new image. Seems crazy or is it possible?

I don't know if there is anyone with enough patience to see the code, if not, if someone at least knows a new approach. Thank you very much, I have been trying to resolve this for some time.

```
function Stories(){

  const files = [ 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg' , 'video3.mp4' ]

  const videoRef = useRef()
  const imageRef = useRef()

  const [ index , setIndex ] = useState(0); // the index starts at 0... first file...
  const [ focus, setFocus ] = useState(null); 


   // Every time the index of the storie is changed. This effect happens.

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const video = videoRef.current;
    const image = imageRef.current;
   
    if( files[index].includes('mp4')){

      video.style.display = "inline"
      video.src = files[index];



      // when i put it i put something in the "setFocus" 
      // triggers a useEffect for the "focus" 
      // that makes the setTimeOut which in the end runs
      // this same script again after a certain time.
      setFocus(files[index]);
      

      // if there is any image in the DOM, hide it
      if( image ) {
        image.style.display = "none";
      }

      //In case the files [index] is an image.
    } else {

      image.style.display = "inline"
      image.src = files[index];
      setFocus(files[index])
      

      // if there is any video in the DOM, hide it
      if ( video ){
        video.style.display = 'none';
        video.muted = true
      }
      
    }

  },[index])


  function back(){
    if( index <= 0 ) return 
    setIndex( index - 1);

  }
  function next(){
    if ( index < files.length - 1) setIndex( index + 1 );
  }



  // This useeffect fires every time a file comes into focus.
  useEffect(() => {
    const timelapse = 5000;

    // I wait for the video to finish to advance to the next index
    if( files[index].includes('mp4')){

       videoRef.current.addEventListener('ended',() =>  setIndex( index + 1 ));
     } 
     
     // If it's an image, so..
     else {

      setTimeout(() => {
        if( focus !== null && index < files.length - 1){
        setIndex(index + 1);
        }
      }, timelapse )
     }
  },[focus])


            // HTML
  return <>
           <video ref={videoRef}/> 
           <img ref={imageRef} />
         
          <button onClick={back}> back </button>
          <button onClick={next}> next </button>
  </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the ID of the `timeout` and cancel it like this:

```js
const timeout = setTimeout(() => { console.log("woo") }, 5000)
window.clearTimeout(timeout)
```

So one approach would be to store that and cancel the timeout when your `back` or `next` functions are invoked.

Another approach would be to use state to record the remaining time and use a timer (`setInterval`) that counts down every second and advances the slide if it reaches zero. Then onClick you can just re-set the time remaining to 5 seconds.

```
const CarouselExample = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(5)
  const [slide, setSlide] = setState(1)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const countdown = window.setInterval(() => {
      setTime(timeRemaining => {
        if (timeRemaining - 1 < 0) {
          setSlide(prevSlide => prevSlide + 1)
          return 5
        } else {
          return timeRemaining - 1
        }
      })
    }, 1000)

    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(countdown)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Current Slide: {slide}</div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setTime(5)
          setSlide(prev => prev + 1)
        }}
      >
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I liked your second approach, I will try to implement it. It seems possible as you see, to create some logic just like I did in which the timer varies depending on whether it is a video in which I expect the 'ended' event instead of setTime?

Comment: Sometimes you can see something, Seniors stuff.

Comment: I understand the logic, useEffect is only executed once and is no longer accessed. So you can hardly deter this timer, right? Maybe I have to try something else

Comment: I'm trying so far haha, I found out that the "ended" event is not made for multiple calls, it ends up doing the same tsunami effect. I'll have to think something, but I appreciate the effort

Comment: Oh so with a video I would set the remaining time to equal the video length when it starts playing, and then listen for changes to the playback to do whatever is most appropriate (e.g. if it's paused, maybe set the timer to a few seconds?)

Comment: Wow, I can't imagine what this is like. But I think that the situation of the pause is already beyond what I need, since it is already difficult to make only this carousel with the image e video situation.